# How Do I Implement ServerSentEvent with Django Channels Using AsyncHttpConsumer

Tags: django-channels

I tried to implement ServerSentEvents using the AsyncHttpConsumer class from Django Channels, but when connection is made, message that is sent from the server never arrives to the client, and I don't understand why I am encountering this problem. Please I need help.

```
consumers.py

from channels.generic.http import AsyncHttpConsumer
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import asyncio

class ServerSentEventsConsumer(AsyncHttpConsumer):

    async def handle(self, body):
        
        await self.send_headers(
            headers= [
                (b"Cache-Control", b"no-cache"),
                (b"Content-Type", b"text/event-stream"),
                (b"Transfer-Encoding", b"chunked"),
            ],
        )

        await self.send_body(
            body= b"Hello world",
            more_body= True
        )

class IndexConsumer(AsyncHttpConsumer):

    async def handle(self, body):

        self.template_str = render_to_string("index.html", {})
        self.template_bytes = bytes(self.template_str, encoding= "utf-8")

        await self.send_response(
            status= 200,
            headers = [
                (b"Content-Type", b"text/html"),
            ],
            body= self.template_bytes,
        )

urls.py

from django.urls import re_path
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from chat.consumers import ServerSentEventsConsumer, IndexConsumer

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"chat/$", ServerSentEventsConsumer.as_asgi()),
    re_path(r"index/$", IndexConsumer.as_asgi()),
    re_path(r"", get_asgi_application())
]

index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
<script>

    const serverSentEvent = new EventSource(`http://${window.location.host}/chat/`)

    serverSentEvent.addEventListener("open", (ev) => {
        console.log("Connection has been established")
    })
    serverSentEvent.addEventListener("message", (ev) => {
        console.log(ev)
    })

</script>
</html>
```

The IndexConsumer class uses the index.html file to attempt connection to the ServerSentEventConsumer class and when connection is made, the ServerSentEvent class sends a Hello world message to the client.